# Fractional Unicode Bars

Tags: code-golf, unicode

Your program should take as input a number `n` that is greater than 0 and output a bar composed of `n // 8` ▉ characters (U+2588), as well as a final character which should be one of ▉ ▊ ▋ ▌ ▍ ▎▏(U+2589 to U+258F) representing `n % 8`. If `n % 8` is 0, your program should not output any additional characters. This is difficult to explain well in text, so here are some examples:

```
Input: 8
Output: █
Input: 32
Output: ████
Input: 33
Output: ████▏
Input: 35
Output: ████▍
Input: 246
Output: ██████████████████████████████▊
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins.

Comment: what if `n%8` == 1?

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer It looks like U+2589 has been left out of the list; it's probably meant to be there.

Comment: @py3_and_c_programmer Sorry, I forgot a character.

Comment: What are the constraints on `n`? "a number" is too imprecise. Obviously it must be an integer, and it must not be negative. But can it be 0?

Comment: @m90 Clarified.

Comment: Note that the rendering of these characters is quite random (depending on the browser, OS, etc.). They look OK on my mobile and terrible on my laptop.

Comment: Your examples seem to be wrong, with the repeating character being U+2589 instead of U+2588.

Comment: @m90 Fixed them, sorry about that

Answer (score 15):

## Excel (ms365), 56 bytes

- -2 Bytes thanks to @[EngineerToast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast)

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REPT("█",A1/8)&IF(MOD(A1,8),UNICHAR(9616-MOD(A1,8)),)
```

Comment: You can leave off the `""` in the second part of the `IF()` if you want it to return blank. Saves 2 bytes. Also, you can get it down to 52 bytes with this alternative: `=REPT("█",A1/8)&IFERROR(MID("▏▎▍▌▋▊▉",MOD(A1,8),1),)`

Comment: @EngineerToast, thanks for thinking along. I had exactly your 2nd suggestion under copy paste a few hours ago but decided against it. The actual [bytecount](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) appeared to be bigger. Chars vs. Bytes is usually the same for Excel, but not the case here with unicode chars.

Comment: Good point! I was using `LEN()` which just counts characters no matter how many bytes each is.

Comment: @JvdV - surely this is [57 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%3DREPT%28%22%E2%96%88%22%2CA1%2F8%29%26LET%28a%2CMOD%28A1%2C8%29%2CIF%28a%2CUNICHAR%289616-a%29%2C%29%29) for 55 characters?

Comment: Woops yes it is @DominicvanEssen. Rollback it is. Sharp eye

Answer (score 13):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 27 bytes

```julia
!n='▐'.-diff((0:8:n)∪n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//9fMc9W/dG0Cep6uimZaWkaGgZWFlZ5mo86VuVp/i8oyswrycnT08jKzwSSeooahlbGZpqamv8B)

Generates a range from 0 to n with step 8, and n itself force-included. Then taking the `diff` produces our codepoint offsets, e.g. `35` gives `8 8 8 8 3`, etc. Returns character arrays.

Analogous solution in R:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```julia
\(n)intToUtf8(9616-diff(c(0:(n/8-.1)*8,n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3tWM08jQz80pC8kNL0iw0LM0MzXRTMtPSNJI1DKw08vQtdPUMNbUsdPI0NTUhWtYVJxYU5FRqGFoZm-mkQQUXLIDQAA)

Thanks to amelies and MarcMush for -3 and -5 on Julia and pajonk for -1 on R.

Comment: -3 using union Unicode operator `!n=Char.(9616-diff((0:8:n)∪n))`

Comment: -5 by using the literal Char [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//9fMc9W/dG0Cep6uimZaWkaGgZWFlZ5mo86VuVp/i8oyswrycnT08jKzwSSeooahlbGZpqamv8B "Julia 0.7 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>43 41</s> 36 bytes

```python
lambda n:~-n//8*'▉'+chr(9608-n%-8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqk43T1/fQkv90bROde3kjCINSzMDC908VV0Lzf9p@UUKmQqZeQpFiXnpqRqGOgqGBgaaVlwKBUWZeSUaxSVFGpmaelVpmTk5GkaaOgrqunbqOgppQEHN/wA) (Fails for n=0)

- -2 thanks to 97.100.97.109
- -5 thanks to loopy walt

(Note: 9608 is the decimal value of 0x2588)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk9f30JL/dG0TnXt5IwiDUszQzPdPFULTS0NIGlnqPk/Lb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXD0MBA04pLoaAoM69Eo7ikSCNTU68qLTMnR8NIU0dBXddOXUchDSio@R8A)

Comment: @97.100.97.109 - thanks. I think you meant `n%8>0` rather than `n%8>1`.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqk43T1/fQkv90bROde3kjCINSzMDC908VV0Lzf9p@UUKmQqZeQpFiXnpqRqGBgaaVlwKBUWZeSUaxSVFGpmaelVpmTk5GkaaOgrqunbqOgppQEHN/wA). Fails for n=0 but that seems ok per OP.

Answer (score 10):

## x86-64 machine code, <del>18</del> 16 bytes

```
AB B8 88 25 00 00 83 EE 08 77 F5 29 F0 48 AB C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLRjtowEHyOv2KbCsk5AoJwUARHq@qke6IvbU@qBAgZxwFXxm5tcwQhfr3p2iDRPsRZz87Mji3zzpbzpnkvNVeHUsCT86U03d1HcoeU4UyJ/7Ej3zEbIMLcHih8TSnpbpXZMAUVsZPEeeNKUk2SvXkDweocenUxHI9J4g4bEE7mgPVPBvaGBArCJCp/k8QKT7IUsil5M7KEisaRa/8ALgepPehsCrFlKZIICdieSU0zckYX4a@56fx5/Xk@zyEVev36rfv6/aUzTlGR3AzBCndQfjHsFytEK2OBBi8JM@hP8fc0g6KHRbudkQStMSHzkscQovZ8sULmeVDkMBjgN8yheBxd0CqJMbEZPfoj@ITV5KqRnf6HMC6p6HV@Hg6E@@Mvi7KKztOWXPqWckudYi@/xQycC/mHtdRfGN9JLYCbUkziycLcGuf2cjjhtjRwvgug1St@oOVpRulBO7nVooRwFQ@ZzRZ1u73Kphc47qQSQE/wDm3q50G8sLsHbUnYnLxwWYxXY/vSNH94pdjWNZ396BEXfBozFAj1Fw)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI an address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated UTF-32 string, and takes the number `n` in ESI. The starting point is after the first byte.

In assembly:

```
r:  stosd           # Write EAX to the string, advancing the pointer.
f:  mov eax, 0x2588 # (Start here) Set EAX to 0x2588.
    sub esi, 8      # Subtract 8 from the input number in ESI.
    ja r            # Jump back if the number was greater than 8.
    sub eax, esi    # Subtract ESI from EAX, increasing it by 0 to 7.
    stosq   # Write RAX (the 64-bit register containing EAX) to the string,
            #  advancing the pointer. Because it's little-endian,
            #  the first 32 bits are the value of EAX, and the next 32 bits are 0
            #  (as the high bits are zeroed when operating on only EAX)
            #  to add the null terminator.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
s8Ẉ⁽"s_Ọ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer and yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Y4uGujkeNe5WK4x/u7vn//7@RiRkA)**

#### How?

```
s8Ẉ⁽"s_Ọ - Link: integer, n   e.g. 17
 8       - eight
s        - split (implicit [1..n]) into chucks of length (8)
                                   [[1..8],[9..16],[17]]
  Ẉ      - length of each          [8,8,1]
   ⁽"s   - 9616
      _  - subtract (vectorises)   [9608,9608,9615]
       Ọ - cast to characters      ['█','█','▏']
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), <sup>66 65 64</sup> 46 bytes

```factor
[ [1,b] 8 group [ length ] map 9616 v-n vabs ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU2H0GBPP3crhdzEkgy9osS89NRihfSi_NKCzLx0heLUwtLUvGSgUGY-REVZKkhbsYI1l6mBQrShTlLs0tKSNF2Lm3rREK6CBUS7QrRCTmpeekmGQixQZ4GCpZmhmUKZbp5CWWJSsQJU1yaQTLRCQVFmXglQXWpicgZEYsECCA0A)

- -1 byte from Mama Fun Roll
- -1 more by taking an entirely different approach
- -18(!) by porting Jonathan Allan's amazing [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254276/97916).

Comment: Perhaps `- neg` instead of `swap -` to save a byte?

Comment: @MamaFunRoll Nice thinking, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

*-2 thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```javascript
f=n=>n?Buffer([226,150,144-(q=n>7?8:n)])+f(n-q):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDoIwEADAr@yN3RQawAoGLSQmvsCj8UCgJRiyhVL9fuU2p/n0v34f/LyGjN1oYrSadcvd/Wut8fgqyyotznlaKJXhprmtu0vD9CZhkbONmiSJ1nlk0JBfgeGmoVIHhCAYHO9uMXJxE7IM7hn8zBOSXPvxwSOeCAQcD1H8Aw)

#### How?

We use `Buffer()` to build the characters from their UTF-8 encodings.

For instance, the character with code point `9608` (0x2588) is generated with:

```javascript
Buffer([226,150,136]) // 0xE2, 0x96, 0x88
```

That's a bit lengthy, but still shorter than the infamous `String.fromCharCode(9608)`.

Comment: You don't need that `%8` do you?

Comment: @Neil Which `%8` are you talking about? :-p

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⭆⪪×ψＮ⁸℅⁻⁹⁶¹⁶Ｌι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaAQX5GSWaIRk5qYWa1TqKHjmFZSW@JXmJqUWaWhq6ihYALEzUHNicglQxDczr7RYw9LM0ExHwSc1L70kQyNTEwSs//83MjH7r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   ψ            Predefined variable null byte
  ×             Repeated by
    Ｎ           Input integer
 ⪪              Split into substrings of maximum length
     ⁸          Literal integer `8`
⭆               Map over substrings and join
             ι  Current substring
            Ｌ   Length
       ⁻        Subtract from
        ⁹⁶¹⁶    Literal integer `0x2590`
      ℅         Convert to Unicode
```

Answer (score 4):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 25 bytes

```
O>a8/`"len"map9616- _ c>S
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Port of @Jonathan Allan's clever Jelly answer!

For testing purposes:

```
[8 32 33 35 246] ( ; n>o ) map
O>a8/`"len"map9616- _ c>S
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
O>a 8/` \len map 9616- _ c>S
```

Assuming input *n*.

- `O>a` range [0, *n*)
- `` 8/` `` chunk into lengths of max 8
- `\len map` get lengths of each chunk
- `9616- _` subtract from 9616
- `c>S` convert to fractional block char

---

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 38 bytes

```
8/%"█"rot ** >o""Q"9616- _ c>S >o"&#
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Outputs the bars.

For testing purposes:

```
[8 32 33 35 246] ( ; ""n>o ) map
8/%"█"rot ** >o""Q"9616- _ c>S >o"&#
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
8/% "█" rot ** >o dup ( 9616- _ c>S >o ) &#
```

- `8/%` divmod by 8
- `"█" rot **` repeat `█` <div part> times
- `>o` output
- `dup (...) &#` execute if <mod part> is truthy (i.e. greater than 0)...

  - `9616- _ c>S` convert to fractional block char
  - `>o` output

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>46</s> 36 bytes

```ruby
->n{?█*(n/8)<<(n%8>0?9616-n%8:"")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3VXTt8qrtH03r0NLI07fQtLHRyFO1sDOwtzQzNNMFMq2UlDRroWrNCkpLihXSoi1iuaAsYyME0xjBNIUzjUzMYiG6FyyA0AA)

A whopping 10 bytes saved by G B.

Comment: Ruby, 36 bytes: [`->n{?▊*(n/8)<<(n%8>0?9616-n%8:"")}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3VXTt8qrtH03r0tLI07fQtLHRyFO1sDOwtzQzNNMFMq2UlDRroWrNCkpLihXSoi1iuaAsYyME0xjBNIUzjUzMYiG6FyyA0AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 46 bytes

```
\(n)intToUtf8(9616-c(rep(8,n/8),if(b<-n%%8)b))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGSpMQi26WlJWm6Fjf1YjTyNDPzSkLyQ0vSLDQszQzNdJM1ilILNCx08vQtNHUy0zSSbHTzVFUtNJM0NSG6NhQnFhTkVGoYWhmb6QANgwovWAChAQ)

Still not as golfy as [Kirill L's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254265/fractional-unicode-bars#comment564396_254275), unfortunately...

Comment: It looks like the approach that I took with Julia answer saves a few [in R too](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3dWM08jQz80pC8kNL0iw0LM0MzXRTMtPSNErzMvPzNIpTCzUMdPJ0LDR18jQ1NSGa1hUnFhTkVGoYWhmb6aRBBRcsgNAA)

Comment: @KirillL. I was just upvoting your beautiful Julia approach when I saw your message!  Post your R one yourself (after changing ```union``` to ```c```, of course)!

Comment: OK, but `c` won't work as it will produce a duplicate when the range ends precisely on `n`, so yours is very close!

Comment: @KirillL. Looks like a workaround to use `c` may be [one byte shorter](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3tWM08jQz80pC8kNL0iw0LM0MzXRTMtPSNJI1DKw08vQtdPUMNbUsdPI0NTUhWtYVJxYU5FRqGFoZm-mkQQUXLIDQAA).

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
ɾ8ẇvL9616εCṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvjjhuod2TDk2MTbOtUPhuYUiLCIiLCIxNyJd)

Yet another port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[9616-Tr[1^#]&/@Range@#~Partition~UpTo@8]&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/f1ee3d30-f224-4566-9de9-237aa5b00f9d)

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 73 bytes

```
/d/iii//ddii/█//ddi/▉//dd/▊//dii/▋//di/▌//d/▍//ii/▎//i/▏/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf6vz6Wv/18/RT8zM1NfPyUFSD6a1gFmARmdIAaQ7gLSYJluEANI9wBpINWrrw8W7gPSQKpf/38mkeA/AA)

Input is a unary.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 61 bytes

```rust
|n,r|{*r=[9608].repeat((!-n/8)as _);r.push((9615-!-n%8)as _)}
```

A `fn(i32,&mut Vec<u32>)`, where the first argument is `n`, and `r` is a mutable reference to a vector where the output will be stored.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZJBa8IwGIZhR3_FpzBJRq1rO7sarf9hl11EpOsSFGzsknQM1PsYyG677OLB_Sh33C9Zqpna9roQKLzP-37fG-jnVmRSbXZtxiGJphxhWNRmVAEjwDjiZOq5lqCSNJNMwT2N-5nnDnD4lSnWCnbhkltiubgS4bDrXwcjW9CURgqheou3AxxJGOOesNNMThDq-k6npcGlAavDkO-Lu16tBvrkexWVCkLQc4G-pDRW9JFAUyqx1MXAnNyY93nImPY-07g-HPWOlCEdbhqOT3okJRVqTJ_qSIPTfDueREIibCdRivTzCGFinmA7ns9m2kBIP3_3eDBA2IIG1xsXq4YF3IxemfZ5c-Rox8_He8OwvebttXVBC_baa0HrHrRy3PH_9KLduT3q5Yh7c4aKKbdzjipV3SItZj2vRCvxTsWwLhXzK47_vW_5PvNnbTaH7y8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 30 bytes

```
.+
$*
1{1,8}
$.&
T`8-1`▉-▏
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLsNpQx6KWS0VPjSskwULXMOHRtE7dR9P6//@34DI24jI25jI25TIyMQMA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1{1,8}
$.&
```

Convert groups of up to 8 to decimal.

```
T`8-1`▉-▏
```

Map digits to the appropriate Unicode character.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sequences](https://github.com/nayakrujul/sequences), 30 bytes

```
iH8/nx$\▉$""Jfh8%H?9616h-VF:
```

Sequences was definitely not made for this!

**Explained:**

```js
iH8/nx$\▉$""Jfh8%H?9616h-VF:
iH                            // Get an integer input and store in `h`
  8/                          // Divide by 8
    n                         // Convert to integer (floor)
     x$  $                    // This many times:
       \▉                     //   Push the string "▉"
                              // Implicitly put into a list
          ""J                 // Join by empty strings
             f                // Output with no newline
              h               // Push `h`
               8%H            // Mod by 8 and store in `h`
                  ?           // If this is truthy (h != 0)
                       h      //   Push `h`
                   9616 -     //   Subtract from 9616
                         V    //   Get chr of the result
                          F   //   Output with a newline
                           :  // Else: (do nothing)
```

In Sequences there is no way of multiplying an integer with a string, so we have to settle for making a list of that string, repeated, and then join it by an empty string.

Also, Sequences uses the 96 printable ASCII characters as its codepage, but because we have `▉` in our code, we have to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L8ô€gŽb¶αç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//0w4w7Tigqxnxb1iwrbOscOn/0r/MTc) (I've put `J` for join in the footer, but apparently outputting a list of characters is ok)

- -3 thanks to Sʨɠɠan
- -1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

#### Explained

```python
L8ô€gŽb¶αç  # Implicit integer input          17
L           # Inclusive range                 [1, 2, ..., 17]
 8ô         # Split into groups of 8          [1, ..., 8], [9, ..., 16], [17]
   €g       # Length of each                  [8, 8, 1]
     Žb¶    # 9616
        α   # Absolute difference from 9616   [9608, 9608, 9615]
         ç  # chr of each                     ["█", "█", "▏"]
            # Implicit output
```

Comment: `(+(` could be `s-`, but `α` will work in this case

Comment: 9616 can be compressed to `Žb¶`

Comment: Also, you can move the `J` to the footer, since outputting a string as a list of characters is allowed by default.

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan - thanks. I somehow missed `α` in the commands page (even though it's right at the top).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - thanks for the info. I've added that in.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 11, <s>58</s> <s>48</s> 39 bytes

```java
n->"█".repeat(--n/8)+(char)(9615-n%8)
```

-9 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

Doesn't support `n=0`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY9BbsIwEEX3nGIUqZKtjINCSEhBcAPYdElZuMa0pmESOQNVhbLvCXrAXiR1gM1IM6P/3/9HfdHquP/sTaXbFtba0XUE4IitP2hjYTOsAC/sHb2DEeEDJBfh2I3CaFmzM7ABgmVPahX9/f5EibeN1SyUonEpY2E@tJfiuUhzRU@l7BeDsjm/VUH5MLjUbg@nQBd30nan5Z18qP0N6uZkv4Zg2901xQlmOMUcC5xhiekMs3DJMMtxMi06eVOG1N8t21NSnzlpgitXJFwczeGVo5iSUEY@mnT9Pw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                  // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  "█".repeat(        //  Repeat this character
             --n/8)  //  `n-1` integer-divided by 8 times
                     //  (by first decreasing `n` by 1 with `--n`)
  +(char)            //  Append an integer casted to a character:
         (9615-n%8)  //   9615 minus (`n-1` modulo 8)
```

Comment: 39 bytes by not supporting `0`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY9BbsIwEEX3nGIUqZKtjINCSEhBcAPYdElZuMa0pmESOQNVhbLvCXrAXiR1gM1IM6P/3/9HfdHquP/sTaXbFtba0XUE4IitP2hjYTOsAC/sHb2DEeEDJBfh2I3CaFmzM7ABgmVPahX9/f5EibeN1SyUonEpY2E@tJfiuUhzRU@l7BeDsjm/VUH5MLjUbg@nQBd30nan5Z18qP0N6uZkv4Zg2901xQlmOMUcC5xhiekMs3DJMMtxMi06eVOG1N8t21NSnzlpgitXJFwczeGVo5iSUEY@mnT9Pw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online") Rough port of latest Python answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>91</s> <s>81</s> 73 bytes

```go
func f(n int)(s string){
for;n>8;n-=8{s+="▉"}
s+=string(9616-n)
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc4xCsIwFAbgPacInRJMBVst0VJ3N8FRREJpStG-liSdQg_gBVxciuAhPIqrJzGxnd4bfr7_fzzLZni3Ir-IssC1qABVddsoMw9kbYJXZ2TIPzvZQY4lAVyBoURjbVQFJbVINiqFLU8hzLjVsyz43m9Bj9w3Rsg6WSQhUKQK0ynoJ_DwB30dcQhovMnw8eRwy1kcsThm8YpFy6T3BfjMwAeUALfRhS3aO9tcgQDzqyhFPZroYRjvDw)

- -10 bytes by @jdt
- -8 bytes by @Neil

Comment: 73 bytes by not supporting `0`: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc4xCsIwFAbgPacInRJMBVst0VJ3N8FRREJpStG-liSdQg_gBVxciuAhPIqrJzGxnd4bfr7_fzzLZni3Ir-IssC1qABVddsoMw9kbYJXZ2TIPzvZQY4lAVyBoURjbVQFJbVINiqFLU8hzLjVsyz43m9Bj9w3Rsg6WSQhUKQK0ynoJ_DwB30dcQhovMnw8eRwy1kcsThm8YpFy6T3BfjMwAeUALfRhS3aO9tcgQDzqyhFPZroYRjvDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>[44](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13376/is-a-crossed-out-4-still-a-4)</s> 40 bytes

```haskell
f n|n<9=[toEnum$9616-n]
f n='█':f(n-8)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNzXSFPJq8mwsbaNL8l3zSnNVLM0MzXTzYrmA4rbqj6Z1qFulaeTpWmhC1WvmJmbmKdgq5CYW-CpoFJSWBJcU-eQp6CmkAbFGnJGmpkK0oZ6ekUEsRAPMIgA)

-4 bytes by ignoring `n=0`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>54</s></sup> 50 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!

```c
f(*o,n){for(;n>8;n-=8)*o++=9608;*o++=9616-n;*o=0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCsIwEITvPsUSKCT9gVSwRGN8EfUQY1MCMZW24qH01Y3bn7nsMHyzYwrjdWhitDRt88BG23ZUhouQoVCCpW2WqWPFhdxcWRUBveJyii4M8NIuUAbjDlB9PfjWaF/TKgdCmFzSGXt87FXw@xrgBNA5daCglHjOCg4cTZaxhVjfLSzFag5u@zXr3WHXUpLw/RNOkPj@Fggi@byycdNuij9jvW76WHz/)

Comment: 50 bytes by not supporting `0`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCsIwEITvPsUSKCT9gVSwRGN8EfUQY1MCMZW24qH01Y3bn7nsMHyzYwrjdWhitDRt88BG23ZUhouQoVCCpW2WqWPFhdxcWRUBveJyii4M8NIuUAbjDlB9PfjWaF/TKgdCmFzSGXt87FXw@xrgBNA5daCglHjOCg4cTZaxhVjfLSzFag5u@zXr3WHXUpLw/RNOkPj@Fggi@byycdNuij9jvW76WHz/ "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 43 bytes

```
:8,:1%-v
v1-"█"$>:?!
>~{8%:"█"+$?!~}>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pCx8pQVbeMq8xQV@nRtA4lFTsre0Uuu7pqC1UrsIC2ir1iXa1dvs3///91y4xNAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n>8?'█'+f(n-8):Buffer([226,150,144-n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY07DoJAFAB7T/E6dsNHQUSioomJJ7AkFAi7iCFvDawab@Dfbg@4F0ESbexmisns0mPaZHW5lzaKnLUtjzCa4zxcGFpdDJMTtEM6WR44ZzWJPS@w3NHAcn3fxoS2/T78gvF/EHf21uql1VOrh1Z3rW5aXY0YbTdJLBh5sDlL1sCplFtxkPA99LioCUIE7hQQZhEEfgemSSET2IiKOZUoCDpSrGVdYkGos0/zFeZkSMGEbk5p@wE)

52 bytes without `Buffer`:

```javascript
f=n=>n>7?'█'+f(n-8):['▏▎▍▌▋▊▉'[n-1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```c
f(*o,n){for(;*o=n>0;*o++=9608-(n<0)*n)n-=8;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCoMwFET3nuITEBJjIBQqtmov0nZhUyOB9KeopQvx6k0TdTYDw5sZJZRtsfde08zlyGbtBlplrsGLDMZ5cypkKSjWkmXIUDRltXiDE7xag5TBnEDQ2E3WqdZ2tMiBEFatacQeH30t5X0LwjjQmBpoQFbBajhG55ytwLa2ojQ0czD7VNR7CFVNSSoPTzhDascbkoDk8WTnlmTxP6Vt249efP8)

From jdt's solution, support 0

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 43 bytes

```
[9616-((range(1;./8)|8),(.-1)%8+1)]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDsIgFAXA/buHCUSpPmgR4lGMCxMb06aFii45u78ks5r5I3KPnt4oVZ7pPSreunPQNeiT6gz1IRypH3VatyW/RhHCwqHHAI8rAiJ4AQm2bhzcANv7f95@U05fMWUH)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 23 bytes

```
@+9608+{>7?0∾-8;7-}
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RWlnaHRzIOKGkCBAKzk2MDgre/Cdlak+Nz8w4oi+8J2VivCdlaktODs3LfCdlal9CkVpZ2h0c8KoICjihpUzMCk=)

```
@+9608+{>7?0∾-8;7-}
       {              }  # recursive function  with argument 
        >7?             # if x is greater than 7
            0∾           #   prepend zero onto
              -8       #   result of recursive call with agument -8
                  ;      # otherwise
                   7-   #   7-
      +                  # now, add the result of this to
@                        #   the null character
 +9608                   #   +9608
```

We could use the literal character '▉' instead of `@+9608`, but this would prevent the code from being encoded with the [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/) [single byte character system](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn), so the UTF8-encoded code would end-up [longer](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%27%E2%96%88%27%2B%7B%F0%9D%95%A9%3E7%3F0%E2%88%BE%F0%9D%95%8A%F0%9D%95%A9-8%3B7-%F0%9D%95%A9%7D).

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 bytes

```
R8Ap.L9616_C
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrgiwcC_R8LM0MzeKdIUJQmaXRSl5KsYuMLCFcAA)

Yet another port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.